# Subdivide a region into equal parts among n people problem.

Tags: logic

Subdivide a region into equal parts among n people.
Each of the n people is to be satisfied that he has selected at least 1/n of the region and that he has not been required to accept the moves of any of his adversaries.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, define the remaining region as the entire region to be subdivided equally among n people.

Case n = 2. 
Randomly order people 1 to 2.
Person 1 cuts 1/2 of the remaining region; defined as the current piece.
Person 2 either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note.
The last person to make a cut selects the current piece and is done.
The remaining person gets the last piece.
Done.

Case n = 3. 
Randomly order people 1 to 3.
Person 1 cuts 1/3 of the remaining region; defined as the current piece.
Person 2 either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note. 
Person 3 either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note.
The last person to make a cut selects the current piece and is done. .
Decrease n by 1.
Go to Case n = 2.

Case n > 3 
Randomly order people 1 to n. 
Person 1 cuts 1/n of the remaining region; defined as the current piece.
Person 2 either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note. 
Person 3 either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note. 
...
Person n either passes or cuts a smaller piece.  See Note.
The last person to make a cut selects the current piece and is done.
Decrease n by 1.
If n > 3 then 
  go to Case n > 3
else
  go to Case n = 3.

Note:
Smaller piece to be cut is to be contained within current piece.
Redefine current piece as the smaller piece.